# react native: creating blurred elevation (android)

Tags: css, react-native

I have a green background green buttons with icons, so the buttons are "invisible" and only the icons appear:

[image]

I would like to set elevation to the icons, but of course when I set it creates the elevation around the button:

[image]

Is there a way to make the elevation around the icon itself? Maybe blur it somehow? For iOS I'm just using:

```
  shadowColor: '#000000',
  shadowOffset: { height: 1 },
  shadowOpacity: 0.15,
  shadowRadius: 4,
```

Comment: It's called shadow. Your icon image should have shadow applied to have it around icon itself. Or have inset shadow/gradient background on box of button

Comment: This is react-native. So the only way is to install a third party package?